# Present perfect with just

Tags: present-perfect

When I want to say that something has just happened "very recently" I use present perfect  because something has just happened and has a present relevance or because it has just happened only?

Comment: Would you mind posting at least two examples? Your thing either *just happened* or *happened very recently* but *just happened very recently* is much too much

Answer (score 1):

Present perfect is used when an action started in the past and continues to the present.

> We *have eaten*.

might have occurred an hour ago.  However,

> We *have* **just** *eaten*.

means *not too long ago/very recently* we ate.

Not to be confused with

> We *have eaten*, **just**.

which might meaning you very recently finished eating or had a very small meal almost incomplete meal

> We barely had something to eat.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. "We have just eaten" does **not** continue to the present: on the contrary, it has completed just before the present. I would say it is indeed because it has present relevance, the particular relevance being that it is very recent so we are probably still feeling the immediate consequences of the eating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the present perfect or the past simple with the adverb "just" to mean recently or a short time before speaking.

The use of the present perfect and the past simple is dominant in BrE and AmE respectively.

Comment: So, with just we often use present perfect because any thing has just happened will have a present relevance, is that right ?

Comment: You usually use "just" in the present perfect in BrE  to mean a very short time ago. American people tend to use  it in the past simple.